# Show Icon instead of text for the gnome menus?

Tags: 10.04, gnome-panel, menu, icons

[image: 10.04 default gnome menu applet]

Is it possible to use icons instead of text for the menus in the top pannel (shown above)?
If so, How can we do that?

I've tryed gconf-editor setting the Key:
**/desktop/interface/toolbar_style** 
with the value of "**Icons**" but nothing happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

However, you can try out the compact `Main Menu` applet, which has only one icon in the panel. To add it,

1. Right-click on free space in the panel,
2. Choose *Add to Panel...*,
3. Select the *Main Menu* applet,
4. Click *Add*, and
5. finally *Close:*

[image]

Comment: Clear, Easy, Fast, Perfect! tnx!

Answer (score 3):

[Cardapio](https://launchpad.net/cardapio) is another solution you might want to consider.

It provides a bit more functionality than the standard menus (it has a lot of `gnome-do`-style features for quick-launching things) and it's a million times more customisable.

Here's how I have mine set up:

[image]

And yes, I'm a filthy ex-Windows user who still prefers one panel at the bottom.

Comment: I'm new to Ubuntu, so every info I can get is appreciated!